# Error loading KeyStore(PKCS12)

Tags: java, keystore

I want to load a KeyStore with the load method but when I use it I got an error. I don't understant what ECParameter is.

```
try {
FileInputStream is =new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\UZ\\key_privateUZ.p12"));
ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
password="1234".toCharArray();
ks.load(is, password);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

my error:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: Only named ECParameters supported 
at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:171) 
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1788) 
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:202) 
at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:97) 
at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339) 
at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.loadSafeContents(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1441) 
at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1313) 
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214) 
at Main.main(Main.java:21) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Only named ECParameters supported 
at sun.security.ec.ECParameters.decodeParameters(ECParameters.java:202) 
at sun.security.ec.ECParameters.engineInit(ECParameters.java:319) 
at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.init(AlgorithmParameters.java:293) 
at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.decodeParams(AlgorithmId.java:139) 
at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.<init>(AlgorithmId.java:114) 
at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.parse(AlgorithmId.java:381) 
at sun.security.x509.X509Key.parse(X509Key.java:168) 
at sun.security.x509.CertificateX509Key.<init>(CertificateX509Key.java:75) 
at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:705) 
at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:169) 
... 8 more
```

Regars

Wazol

Answer (score 1):

You'll find plenty of information on EC (elliptic curve) parameters if you do a search. In particular, the [JDK Code which throws that exception](http://j6a.ru/_e_c_parameters_8java_source.html).

If you look in the relevant method, you will see a commented out section after the exception which indicates:

> It is left as a starting point for a complete parsing implementation

In other words the JDK doesn't support all possible encodings.

You might have better luck using [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Elliptic+Curve+Key+Pair+Generation+and+Key+Factories) which generally has more features than the basic JDK.

It might also help if you explain how the data in the keystore was generated.

Comment: The final goal is to create a KeyStore from .p12 file and .cvert file.  With this Keystore, I will access to the DG3 of a passport. With Bouncy castle, I don't really understant how to create my keyStore :s.And I don't know how the keystore was generated but I will ask some informations about it

Comment: @shaun This doesn't help provide an answer, just more rabbit trails.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this
In ECKey class
ECParameterSpec  papamSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec(SECP);

Comment: A bit more explanation on why this would be helpful for the OP to understand if your suggestion is helpful