# Exception reading in a public key from a certificate in Java

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, java-security

A website generated key-pairs using the algorithm "SHA256withECDSA" and curve "prime192v1" and let me download the public key that I stored locally in a file called "PublicKey.cer".

Now, I try to read in the key and do a signature verification of a text. The signature was produced by the same website using the private key.

Here is my code that tries to do it all.

```
public class SecurityTest {

    private static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromFile() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("D:\\PublicKey.cer");
            CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            Certificate certificate = f.generateCertificate(fin);
            PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();
            return pk;
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (CertificateException ce) {
            ce.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String sign(String plainText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
        privateSignature.initSign(privateKey);
        privateSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(UTF_8));

        byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
    }

    public static boolean verify(String plainText, String signature, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {

        Signature publicSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
        publicSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
        publicSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(UTF_8));

        byte[] signatureBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature);

        return publicSignature.verify(signatureBytes);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String plainText = "Rakesh";
        String signature = "MDUCGQDT+L5yUkMkNzYJG8S582JIOBFoqPRe1GICGHAcbtQW/w43yQP9Aji6Zv0aacNVb9J1ew==";

        try {
            if (verify(plainText, signature, getPublicKeyFromFile())) {
                System.out.println(plainText + " successfully verified!");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Verification failed");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

When I ran the code, I got the following exception:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: Only named ECParameters supported
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at com.justurshop.test.SecurityTest.getPublicKeyFromFile(SecurityTest.java:19)
    at com.justurshop.test.SecurityTest.main(SecurityTest.java:58)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Only named ECParameters supported
    at sun.security.ec.ECParameters.engineInit(ECParameters.java:150)
    at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.decodeParams(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateX509Key.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Could anyone help? Could you provide code that will read in the Public key from the certificate file?

Comment: Did you try using Bouncy Castle as advised here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545258/error-loading-keystorepkcs12